# How to animate the data in the table on update via ReactCSSTransitionGroup?

Tags: reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

ReactCSSTransitionGroup adds the class only when the component is added or removed, but when data updates it isn`t animated...

Comment: you can edit your question rather than put updates in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For on update animation you can try to use [react-animate-on-change](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animate-on-change) addon